# Best Practices for making a large Python Flask project easy to install? (deployment)

Tags: flask, installation, redis, vtk

I’m working on a Flask app that will be open source and I’m trying to figure out the best way to make the project easily downloadable for people who want to try it out and help develop it. My problem would be solved if it was as simple as telling people to download the repo and install via a requirements.txt. However, the project requires some more “advanced” dependencies including setting up a Redis server and a tool called VTK which has a complicated installation process on Windows.

My team has considered making the project easily downloadable by writing an “install.py” of sorts that calls cmd commands to install everything. This is kind of working, but I feel it is not the best approach. We’re now considering throwing it all into a Docker image instead to simplify the whole process and then just tell developers to install the docker image. Keep in mind that we would ideally want developers to be able to work on Windows, Mac, or Linux.

Is there a generally accepted technique/process used to make a project like this as painless as possible to install?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Docker sounds fine.

Answer (score 0):

Create a Dockerfile for your app and use docker compose to connect it to other tools (such as Redis).

Maybe this example is a good start:
https://www.agiliq.com/blog/2018/10/docker-flask-redis/

And an example Dockerfile for Flask:
https://runnable.com/docker/python/dockerize-your-flask-application

Your users will have to install Docker on their computers to deploy your app.
You can provide them with the Dockerfile, Flask app files and docker-compose.yml

They can deploy your app by simply running the command (from directory with docker-compose.yml):
`docker-compose up`